# Clean install of Windows 10 OEM: license key issues?

Tags: windows-10, oem, product-key

I have been a Linux user after switching from Windows 98 and never looked back. However, a friend asked me to set up their brand-new Lenovo ThinkPad with Windows 10. I was totally startled at how terrible the out-of-the-box UX is. Adware all over the place and no luck getting rid of it the gentle way.

So, this question is not about removing adware per se, but about getting a clean install of Windows 10 going. The two things I'm hesitant about are:

- Where do I get an ISO image for Windows 10?
- Where do I find the OEM license key? Back in the day they used to put stickers on the machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the [Media Creation Tool for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10). That should work for you.

Also Windows 10 moved to [digital entitlement](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-10/activation-in-windows-10). So once the key is activated (Lenovo did it in the factory), if the OS is of the same edition on the same machine, the OS gets automatically activated once it connects to the internet after a clean install. So no need for a sticker.

You can even try [Resetting your Windows 10 PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options). That is as good as a format.