# Buy Windows 10 key for Fujitsu OEM Image

Tags: windows, windows-10, product-key

I have two Fujitsu LIFEBOOK E756. One is a little older and came preinstalled with Windows 7. The second one is recently bought and comes with Windows 10. Of the second one I have created an image and want to deploy that image on the first Notebook. But I am fairly sure that I will get licensing problems. Neither of those Notebooks has a sticker on the bottom where I can find the license key.

My question would be: If I buy a retail Windows 10 key will the OEM image from Fujitsu accept it?

Comment: There is no such thing as an OEM only Windows 10 image.  The only problem people get into, which does have a solution, is attempting to install Windows 10 Professional on a device that came with Windows 10 Home.  How you resolve the conflict that happens in that situation is well documented so I won’t submit an answer explaining how to resolve that conflict because you didn’t ask about it. Answer to your only question is of course it will work because (see the first sentence of my comment).

Comment: “Neither of those Notebooks has a sticker on the bottom where I can find the license key.” - The machine that came preinstalled with Windows 7 is required to have a COA sticker with the license key on it.  The Windows 10 machine, has a COA sticker on it indicating which version of Windows -0 it came with, but the key is embedded in the ACPI table.

Answer (score -1):

If you upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 10 your hardware is registered in Microsoft Database for Windows 10. If you reinstall your older Lifebook with Windows 10 it will be reactivated again after connected to Microsoft licensing servers.

I think you do not need a OEM key.

UPDATE: to be more clear a free upgrade with [Windows 10 Update Assistant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3159635/windows-10-update-assistant) is needed

Comment: I can't imagine that I do not need a key for that image. It's a upgrade to a new/different operating system. Are you sure?

Comment: I don't know if your oem image will work. You can try after upgrade. But you can use any image from Microsoft. See also already answered [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1033160/clean-install-of-windows-10-oem-license-key-issues?rq=1)

Comment: I upgraded my oem hp pc from windows 7 to windows 10 without a key. After upgrade I was able to install new Windows 10 on this hardware without license key because hardware was licensed before with upgrade process (install and skip enter license key). For example what is possible: I decided to upgrade from W10 HOME to W10 PRO version with an windows 7 pro key. I installed W7 Pro in extra partition and made upgrade to W10 Pro. After Registration I was able to upgrade my working Partition from W10 Home to W10 Pro and PC is still licensed 2 times without reinstall.

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with the free upgrade offer and only has confused the author

Comment: @Ramhound maybe you are right and the author confused about answer.
But the point of my answer is if ap0 registered his hardware for Windows 10 (with upgrade or new install with key) it is possible to install the image from other PC and the Windows 10 version will be activated without any action required. Nobody know if the image will work on different hardware.
Do you agree in this basics?

Comment: @Rainer - Author seemed to have no problem understanding your answer, I like the author, fail to see the relevance of the digital entitlement system that Windows 10 uses.  You did see the part about how he has two different devices right?  So the digital entitlement of the Windows 10 devices which has Windows 7 installed on it currently isn't relevant, since Windows 7 doesn't use a digital entitlement and the digital entitlement of the Windows 10 device cannot be transferred to the first device.

Comment: "Nobody know if the image will work on different hardware." - What do you mean nobody knows?  I absolutely know the answer to that question.  "Do you agree in this basics?" - I absolutely do not agree with the basics of this answer.

Answer (score -1):

The OEM Windows 7 install will not accept a Windows 10 key.

You can use the download tool here :- https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10

to download a Windows 10 ISO that will accept a windows 10 licence key.

Comment: Thats not what I ment. I have a OEM Image from Fujitsu (Windows 10) and I want to buy a Windows 10 key for that image.

Comment: If the machine has an OEM Licence for windows 10, you won't need a key for it.

If the OEM image is Windows 7, you will need the OEM Licence for windows 7.

If you want to update the windows 7 machine to windows 10, you will need a windows 10 licence, and do a full reinstall. I don't recommend using the image from the other machine, as it may be a different type of licence. Buy the retail key, and use the tool above to create media to install windows 10 on the windows 7 machine.

Comment: That's the point. The older machine does not have a Windows 10 license but I want to deploy an Windows 10 image to that machine and then enter a retail Windows 10 key. The question is if the OEM image will accept an Windows 10 retail key. The reason I want to do this is that the image is already configured and has most software installed I need. My goal was to prevent having to install everything from scratch.

Comment: It may not. You'll need to buy the key anyway, so buy the key and try the OEM Image. If it works, great, if not, use the tool above to do a full reinstall. (updated my comment while you added your second one, sorry)